# Paragon Levels in D3: Reaper of Souls

Tags: diablo-iii

Since Reaper of Souls was announced I wondered what will happen to the current characters' paragon levels.

- Will the combined paragon experience from all chars be used for the new global paragon level or...
- will the highest level be used and all others discarded?

Basically I want to know if it does make sense to paragon-level other characters besides my main before the add-on.

Comment: Sorry, @Erik.  Since Reaper of Souls isn't out yet, we can't answer this, so I'm voting to close.

Comment: lemme make a wild guess: it will stay as it is unless you buy the expansion and push your characters to there. Just like it was with Diablo 2: LoD. There are now classic characters(Diablo 2) and expansion characters(Diablo 2: LoD), both having their own games. So why wouldn't Blizzard keep it in Diablo 3? Classic and expansion chars

Comment: @Novarg It's announced that paragon 2.0 will be a patch BEFORE reaper of souls is released.

Comment: @fbueckert This question wouldn't make any sense if RoS was already released, would it? Besides, there were RoS press conferences, so this question can be answered.

Comment: @ErikAigner Answerability doesn't even come into play, I'm afraid.  Since the game has not been released, we do not allow questions about it.  We're not a news service; if you want to find out details about unreleased games, you can go to another site, since all we'd be doing is repeating what's already been said.  Once the game is out, however, we will happily help you with any questions you might have about it.

Comment: This is answerable if you play on the PTR. While they may change it, the current system is a cumulative of all of your characters seperating the hardcore and softcore. While I agree with some of the posters. This was an unreleased game until Dec 12th when the PTR made it so anyone can get online and check.

Comment: Should this be reopened now that Paragon 2.0 is out, and edited? The answer is currently wrong so leaving it open in its current form is not a good solution either. I will edit the answer tonight if noone beats me to it, and I'll then nominate the question for reopening afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Paragon 2.0**

- No paragon level caps
- Account wide paragon points
- All existing paragon experience will be consolidated and paragon points will be given
- Paragon points can be spent on customizing stats
- So far, 4 stats
- Core

  - Intelligence +5 [0/50].
  - Strength +5 [0/50].
  - Dexterity +5 [0/50].
  - Vitality +5 [0/50].
- Attack

  - Crit Chance +0.2% [0/50].
  - Crit Damage +1% [0/50].
  - Attack Speed +0.2% [0/50].
  - Cooldown Reduction +0.2% [0/50].
- Defense

  - Health % [0/50].
  - Resist All [0/50].
  - Armor [0/50].
  - Dodge % [0/50].
  - Block Chance % [0/50].
- Utility

  - Movement Speed [0/50].
  - Gold Pick-up Radius [0/50].

Points/stats can be reset, meaning you can reset your allocation and reassign to another stat

Source: [battle.net](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/7961416762)